Mismatch between equivalent definitions of the Bohr compactification of the reals
I feel I'm overlooking something very silly.
The Bohr compactification of $\mathbb R$ has two equivalent definitions.

The set of (possibly discontinuous) homomorphisms $\mathbb R \to \mathbb T$ under the pointwise topology.

The maximal ideal space of the set $AP(\mathbb R)$ of almost periodic functions. i.e the set of multiplicative linear functionals under the pointwise topology.


To represent an element of 1 as a functional we use the fact that $AP(G)$ is the closure of functions of the form
$$ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x}$$
Given a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb T$ we can form the corresponding functional by sending each  $e^{i \lambda x} \mapsto \phi(\lambda)$. Since exponentials with different $\lambda_i$ are linearly independent, we can extend the above to all linear combinations by linear independence, i.e
$$ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto \sum c_i \phi(\lambda_i).$$
The fact that the above is multiplicative follows from the exponential multiplication rules and how $\phi$ commutes with multiplication.
Finally we extend the functional to all of $AP(\mathbb R)$ by continuity.
What confuses me is that the above makes perfect sense if $\phi$ is instead a homomorphism $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C^ \times$ (complex numbers under multiplication). For simplicity let $\phi(\lambda) = e^\lambda$. Then we can define the functional
$$ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto \sum c_i e^{\lambda_i}.$$
This functional does not correspond to a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb T$.
What am I missing?

I don't see why your functional (at the end) is bounded, and hence why it extends to all of AP(R) by continuity.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an elementary oversight

@YemonChoi I see now what the problem is. We need boundedness of the functional to extend it to the closure. And the homomorphisms $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C^\times$ with nonzero real part yield unbounded functionals.

@YemonChoi Would you happen to know if it's easy to prove the functionals $ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto \sum c_i \phi(\lambda_i)$ are continuous? It should be enough to prove the component functionals $ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto \sum c_j$ are continuous but even that is escaping me for the moment.

This will not be continuous because the sequence of almost periodic functions $e^{-n} e^{i n x}$ converges to zero as an almost periodic function but the value of the functional on each element of the sequence is $e^{-n} e^n=1$.

Ah, I see now. You need continuity (equivalent to boundedness) wrt the max-norm in order to extend to the closure. And the guys that don't map into the circle are all unbounded.

If you don't mind, is it hard to show the function
$ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto \sum c_i \phi(\lambda_i)$ is continuous over the space of linear combinations? This amounts to proving each projection function
$ \sum c_i e^{i \lambda_i x} \mapsto c_j$ is continuous. I am aware this will be proved in any harmonic analysis textbook in much greater generality. But I am just getting a feel for the subject at the moment and would like to keep things concrete.
